# How i can prevent the negative value in delay in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to stop the countdown when is finished, now it continues with a delay of negative numbers.

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
timer: 5
};}    

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = { timer: 30 };
}

startTimer = () => {
this.clockCall = setInterval(() => {
this.decrementClock();
 }, 1000);
}

decrementClock = () => {  
this.setState((prevstate) => ({ timer: prevstate.timer-1 }));
};

componentWillUnmount() {
 clearInterval(this.clockCall);
}
```

Comment: This is the *wrong* way to implement a clock. To implement a clock correctly, you have to save the time when starting (`new Date()`) and update more often, e.g. every 100ms. When updating, you should set the time to the difference of current time and start date.

Comment: Sorry my skills in react is basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clear interval if it is going to be negative:

```js
startTimer = () => {
  this.clockCall = setInterval(() => {
    if (this.state.timer === 0) {
      clearInterval(this.clockCall)
      return
    }
    this.decrementClock();
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: How can I pause and resume the countdown?, thank you

Answer (score 1):

[setState method](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) has a second argument as a callback, you could use it to check if the countdown has finished.

```
decrementClock = () => {  
  this.setState((prevstate) => ({ timer: prevstate.timer-1 }), () => {
    if (this.state.timer < 1) {
      clearInterval(this.clockCall);
    }
  });
};
```